# How to center align a Section item in a Form

Tags: forms, swiftui, sections

I am trying to center align an array of views inside a section, however all I get is leading alignment.  I tried using `VStack` instead of `HStack`, and using `.frame(width: ..., alignment: .center)` but these don't work for me.  If I substitute the `ScrollView` with a `Text` then that works.  I'm using Xcode 12.3 and iOS 14.3.

```
struct TestSectionAlign : View {
    var body : some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("background color")) {
                viewForBackgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
    var viewForBackgroundColor : some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ScrollView.init(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(0..<15) { i in
                        Button(action: {
                            // do something
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "circle.fill").foregroundColor(Color.init(white: Double(i)/16.0))
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) 
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are trying to fight with scrollView concept! ScrollView can be horizontal or vertical. if you noticed to ScrollView on vertical it start from top to bottom, also in  horizontal from left to right! if you want center aliment you should start working on position of your viewForBackgroundColor and if you want be scrollable you should work on gesture of viewForBackgroundColor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using GeometryReader, then setting manually width of the HStack and aligning it center

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body : some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("background color")) {
                viewForBackgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
    var viewForBackgroundColor : some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                ScrollView.init(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        ForEach(0..<15) { i in
                            Button(action: {
                                // do something
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "circle.fill").foregroundColor(Color.init(white: Double(i)/16.0))
                            }
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center) //<< here now center
                }
            }.border(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, this works fine as long as the count of views fits on the screen -- once there's more it's not possible to scroll horizontally to either end.  Try your code with 45 items and subdivide the white by 46.